# svn to git conversion

Tags: git, ubuntu, svn, git-svn

I am trying to convert a SourceForge project from Subversion to Git. According to some Googling, it should be possible to use this command:

```
git svn clone http://PROJECT.svn.sourceforge.net/ PROJECT.git
```

Where `PROJECT` is the project name at SourceForge, to get a SVN project checked out into a local git repository.

However this just gives the following error message:

> ```
> Initialized empty Git repository in /home/user/git/PROJECT.git/.git/
> Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/lib/perl5/SVN/Core.pm line 584.
> XML data was not well-formed:  at /usr/bin/git-svn line 1385
> ```

I am using Kubuntu 8.10 and Git is version 1.5.6.3.

I found a [bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=464797) reported on Fedora that seem to be similar, but it has not been resolved, so I do not know where the problem is. Am I using the command incorrectly, or is it a bug?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From a [svn project page](http://sourceforge.net/scm/?type=svn&group_id=234930) it looks like you are using the wrong URL - try:

```
git svn clone http://PROJECT.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/PROJECT PROJECT.git
```

I just successfully checked one out (with git 1.6.2 on OS X 10.5) with:

```
git svn clone http://javaautoupdater.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/javaautoupdater ok.git
```

Comment: Thank you, that was it. That error message was not very helpful though.

Comment: yeah, took a bit of searching around to find it - the main hint to me was that svn log wasn't working with the URL type you were using

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and it turns out that I had just rebooted and needed to ssh-add my keys back in. Try ssh'ing into the box that git-svn is trying to connect to and see what error you get.

Answer (score 0):

Try a tool called svn2git. Read here for details: https://help.github.com/articles/importing-from-subversion.